# Cygwin make package

Tags: android-ndk, cygwin

I am trying to run android ndk-build command in the cygwin terminal.

When I do it is telling me ...

> ERROR: Cannot find 'make' program. Please install Cygwin make package
>   or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it.

The thing is, I believe I have all the cygwin packages installed. And other topics have suggested running installing and being sure to check the devel>make option as a package. Porblem is, is that there seems to be no make option in the devel package folder.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score -1):

NDK comes with its own `make`, the copy that comes with `cygwin` has quite a few incompatibilities. You don't need `cygwin` at all to run the latest versions of NDK (since r6, IIRC). I usually run `ndk-build.cmd` in a `CMD` window where cygwin is not on the `PATH`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I can compile without cygwin. But I have super slow link times, so I am really just trying anything to improve them.

Comment: Cygwin can not improve your link times. All NDK toolchains are Win32-native executables